# Hide toolbar on RecyclerView scroll causes text to move into notification bar

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, toolbar

In an application I am just starting, I have a RecyclerView.
I used the following code to hide the toolbar when scrolling through the RecyclerView:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

When scrolling, the toolbar moves but it's text slides into the notification tray instead of disappearing.

At the top of the image in the notification tray it says HarHar and then shows the settings button at the end.

An example of this is:

[Image of toolbar in notification tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqIin.png)

The code for the toolbar is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.harhar.harhar.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />`

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If anyone could help I would truly appreciate it.
Thank you.

```
 if (canHelpMe()){
        eternallyGrateful();
    }else if(needExtraInformation()){
        letMeKnow();
    }else{
        reallySad();
    }
```

Comment: can you share your complete code. (adapter, and activity class file )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the CoordinatorLayout.

So your CoordinatorLayout look like this

e.g.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.harhar.harhar.MainActivity">
```

Let me know if issues still persist

Comment: That was relatively easy. I thought of deleting that at one point and then I said "Nah, that would be too easy".. Moral of the story: always go with your gut. Thanks a lot, you are a boss and this is the answer.

Comment: @Coder123 i am glad to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

adding one toolbar layout in different XML file and then include that XML file it work,
or remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlway`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I am attempting to keep the scroll|enterAlways because I would like to have the toolbar leave if I scroll up.

Comment: Thanks for trying by the way. I appreciate the help.